# Does LINQ to SQL support the t-sql "in" statement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, t-sql

I dont't know how to describe the title better (so feel free to change) but essntial I want to produce the equivilent of the following statement in LINQ to SQL:

```
select * from products where category in ('shoes','boots')
```

The fields will be coming from the query string essentially (more secure than this but for ease of explanation) i.e

```
string[] myfields = request.querystring["categories"].split(',');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you use `Contains`:

```
db.Products.Where(product => myFields.Contains(product.Category))
```

aka

```
from product in db.Products
where myFields.Contains(product.Category)
select product
```

Answer (score 1):

As other have mentioned, yes it does using the .Contains method.  To benefit the other random people that may arrive here via Bing (or any of the other search engines): Linq-To-Entities does not support the .Contains method in the current version.  However, with a simple extension method, you can do so:
http://george.tsiokos.com/posts/2007/11/30/linq-where-x-in/

Answer (score 0):

In theory you would use contains:

```
var productList = from product in context.Products
    where myfields.contains(product.category)
    select product
```

However you'll need to test this - I seem to recall there being a bug in the Linq2Sql optimizer when trying to deal with List<> and array values being used like this (it may have only occured if you tried to cast them as IQueryable)